# Getting Undefined variable: postType on Live website but not Testing Site

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, woocommerce, undefined-index

I'm pretty new with php and coding in general.

For some reason I'm getting: **Notice:** Undefined variable: postType in **/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-custom-product-type.php** on line **213**

On my live website https://sipscene.com/

but not on my stage testing website https://sipscene.tiemstudio.com/

I cant manage to find out why..

Someone knows? Thank you.

Comment: Are those 2 different hosts, check your error log level, look like your testing site disables log warning level while production site allows it. Take a look at this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Comment: I have checked it out and both live and staging site have the same wp-config file